# Using of adverbs very and really before an adjective

Tags: adverbs

> He was really frightened. It seemed to him as his nightmare came true.
>
> He was very frightened. It seemed to him as his nightmare came true.

What is the difference between these two sentences in meaning, and which one is correct to use?

Answer (score 1):

Depending on how you interpret the words, there could be a great deal of difference.

> He was *really* frightened.

He wasn't faking it. Instead of just giving a performance, he was *actually* frightened.

> He was *very* frightened.

It was more than just a little bit of fear. He was *extremely* frightened.

That aside, if you interpret *really* to mean the same thing as *very*, then it's just personal choice and neither is more correct than the other.

Comment: @curiousdannii This is not a proofreading question. Proofreading is asking to have any errors corrected, and I would have voted to close it as such if I thought that was the case.

Comment: @curiousdannii I disagree. The main question is *What is the difference?* (And asking which to choose is a valid question, even though it's not one that can normally be answered objectively—which I indicate in the last sentence of my answer.)

Comment: @SanjarIgamov Being presented with a passage and then asked to check it for errors (proofreading) is off topic for this site. If there is a suspicion that something is wrong, it needs to be a specific concern that is brought up rather than something in general.

Comment: What do you mean "off-topic proofreading questions?" I thought they had the same meaning, however, recently I have come across with some sentences in which they prefer using really to very, that is why I am asking. If you don't know the answer you don't have to answer, no one asked you to! Perhaps, it is beyond your knowledge just like mine.

Comment: I agree that _He was really frightened_ could in certain contexts be interpreted as _He was actually frightened_. A more common word order to express this second meaning would probably be: _He really was frightened_.

Comment: @SanjarIgamov I agree with you. That's why I answered your question. :) My earlier comments were in response to somebody else (who has since deleted their comments), not to you.

Comment: Thnxxx, I really appreciate!